# Spring integration DSL :: facing issue when calling channel from the xml

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I did one simple DSL which retrieves the data from database and doing simple conversion in the service activator.

```
    @Bean
public IntegrationFlow mainFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("userChannel")
                .channel("queryChannel")
                .handle("sampleConvertor","convertUser")
                .get();
```

queryChannel is a jdbc outbound gateway and sampleConverter is the service Activator.

```
<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway query="select * from employee where employee_id=:payload"
request-channel="queryChannel" data-source="dataSource"/>
```

The issue is after retrieving the data from database, the flow is not going to serviceActivator and it simply returns back the database response.

In xml configuration, I used to invoke gateway inside the chain like below.

```
<int:gateway id="query.gateway" request-channel="queryChannel"/>
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bit unusual to combine Java DSL and XML configuration, but they still work together.

Your problem I think that you are missing the fact that your `queryChannel` has two subscriber at runtime, not a chain of call.

The first one is `<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>` and the second is that `.handle("sampleConvertor","convertUser")`. Right, when you declare a channel in the `IntegrationFlow`, the next EIP-method produces a *subscriber* for this channel. At the same time when you use a channel like `request-channel` or `input-channel` in the XML configuration that brings a subscriber as well.

So, you have two subscriber on the `DirectChannel` with the `RoundRobinLoadBalancingStrategy` and therefore only one of them will handle a message and if it is a request-replly component, like that `<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>` it will produce a message into the `output-channel` or to the `replyChannel` in the headers. In your case the story is exactly about a `replyChannel` and therefore you don't go to the `.handle("sampleConvertor","convertUser")` because it's not the next in the chain, but just a parallel universe by the round-robin algorithm.

If you really would like to reach that `.handle("sampleConvertor","convertUser")` after calling the `<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>`, you should consider to use `.gateway("queryChannel")` instead of that `.channel()`.

Comment: replacing .channel with .gateway did the trick! Thank you so much.